# How do I update Jira custom field values via REST api

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to update "matter" field (single select list). What is the best way to do that?

I have a values in bulk (more than 100) to be added to the custom field. Is there any way i can do this by using an API. I have also checked the [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis)

But nothing is mentioned here as well.

Comment: Related question on Atlassian's site: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-I-update-Jira-custom-field-via-REST-api/qaq-p/498231

Answer (score 5):

Just add the customfield to the issue json like

```
{ "fields": {"customfield_XXXX": "value"} }
```

where XXXX is the customfield number. You can get it by looking at the custom field screen on Jira and look at the link shown in the browser bar by hovering you mouse on the custom field action links.

Moreover you said that is a single select list so the value will be only ONE.

If you intend to CREATE or EDIT a customfield on the fly with 100 choices it is a completely different problem.

Check [this unresolved suggestion](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-28539?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) on the Atlassian website for advice. The issue contains also a workaround with a custom plugin available.

Comment: Can you please explain how can i do that.

Comment: I do not understand your question. I've already replied, what exactly do you want to know with "how can I do that"? [Here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues) there are examples with curl you can try...

Comment: Thanks for this. Atlassian completely failed in their documentation here.